# How to understand commutative ring spectra?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Or how to understand simplicial rings, topological rings, or similar models? What are the intuitions on their homotopy groups and their graded ring $\pi_*$? Any good references?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is about references for structured ring spectra.  In addition to the classical introductions ([EKMM](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/BOOKS/EKMM.pdf), etc.), there are a couple nice review articles written more recently that I like:

- B. Richter, ["Commutative ring spectra"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.02328v1)
- T. Lawson, ["$E_n$ ring spectra and Dyer-Lashof operations"](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/%7Etlawson/papers/dyerlashof.pdf), now published in the [*Handbook of Homotopy Theory*](https://www.routledge.com/Handbook-of-Homotopy-Theory/Miller/p/book/9780815369707), edited by Haynes Miller

There's plenty to say about ring spectra, and one reason I like these articles is that they showcase some of the things you can do with them.